# Read string line from console

Tags: java

I need to create an array from console.

I do:

```
int forbiddenSequenceCount = scanner.nextInt();//1
String[] forbidden = new String[forbiddenSequenceCount];//2
for (int k = 0; k < forbiddenSequenceCount; k++) {//3
    forbidden[k] = scanner.nextLine(); //4
}
```

But when I input `forbiddenSequenceCount = 1` line 4 was not waiting while I input String.
 It's just executed.

What i'm doing wrong?

Input :

```
2
3 0 1 0
```

I need put `3 0 1 0` to array.

Comment: your index are false :)

Comment: @romaneso Indexes are fine, the problem is with `nextInt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scanner.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) reads *only* the `int` value, the `'\n'` (the *enter* you press right after you type the `int`) is consumed in [`scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()).

To fix this add `scanner.nextLine()` right after `scanner.nextInt()` so it'll consume that `'\n'`.

Comment: I will accept this answer during9 minutes. Stack disallow me this now.

Comment: @deathember You're welcome, make sure you understand what happened in your code to avoid this problem next time. You can also have a different instance of `Scanner`.. But the solution I provided is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to think of this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i = sc.nextInt();
```

So, in your case, it goes like that:

```
int forbiddenSequenceCount = scanner.nextInt();
String[] forbidden = new String[forbiddenSequenceCount];
for (int k = 0; k < forbiddenSequenceCount-1; k++) {
    forbidden[k] = scanner.next();
}
```